# Venturing into HBA driver development

Tags: storage, driver, linux-device-driver, scsi, iscsi

I'm a mid level developer with acceptable knowledge of OS internals and some driver development but up until now, I've worked mostly on the networking side of things

I’m now venturing into HBA driver development. I’m looking at online material for the same. And most searches online are leading me to open solaris which seems to be the ***only*** guide available online for writing HBA drivers

Is there anything else I can read to help me get up to speed with it? Ive been reading some old books on SAN but they are written from the system admin's perspective. Not from the developer's perspective.

Keen to hear suggestions, esp from active storage developers

Comment: linux-scsi@ mailing list is for your service. Drop a message there, perhaps people will tell you what to do.

Comment: I don't think, it's easy to find answer for this topic online. But if you have knowledge about kernel/drivers development, you can try looking directly into sources. For example, here are sources of the driver for one of the most popular family of Fibre Channel HBA family: https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/12395198

Comment: @MikhailZakharov thanks for the tip. So does it apply to ALL Emulex fibre channel HBAs? Do you have a relatively simple (if older) model in mind that I can download the datasheet for and look at this source? Its only to get my feet wet. The simpler the better.

Comment: Hi @HighOnMeat for nothing! lpfc drivers have a long story behind them and I believe they are back-compatible with each generation and support more or less the same level of functionality (and complexity to study for you). Unfortunately, SAN technologies is a toy mainly for enterprise business because of the price, also SAN/Storage infrastructure develops fast so it's difficult to find old hardware in production. So you'd better look for more or less modern real equipment (and data sheet ) to study.